# Gremlin scala query to get max value of all outgoing Edges of multiple vertices

Tags: scala, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I have to get the vertices having some label (which will return me multiple vertices) and get max value from all outgoing Edges of the vertices.

My query looks like this

```
g.V().hasLabel(id).outE().values("range").max().path().headOption().get
```

it returns something [100].

Is there is better way to do this. It returns list i need only the value

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. At a minimum, please add a minimal graph setup or use one of the example graphs. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve